# Implementing PLU Decomposition in Rust

Tags: rust, linear-algebra

I am using abstalg, because I wanted to learn more about how to do this with generic fields, (So you can implement LU decomposition not just for floats). I used `Matrix2D` to wrap my behaviour and data (essentially like a view of the vector, the reason it is used is because MatrixRing from `abstalg` just uses vectors), but I don't like it, I wouldn't know how else to wrap the behaviour unless you implemented a function for everything, but I don't think that looks pretty either.

```rust
use abstalg::*;
pub struct Matrix2D<'a, F>
where
    F: Field,
{
    field: MatrixRing<F>,
    data: &'a mut Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>,
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
}

impl<'a, F: Field + Clone> Matrix2D<'a, F> {
    pub fn new(field: F, data: &'a mut Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>, rows: usize, cols: usize) -> Self {
        assert_eq!(rows * cols, data.len(), "Data does not match dimensions");
        Matrix2D {
            field: MatrixRing::<F>::new(field, rows),
            data,
            rows,
            cols,
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, row: usize, col: usize) -> &<F as Domain>::Elem {
        assert!(row < self.rows && col < self.cols, "Index out of bounds");
        &self.data[row * self.cols + col]
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, row: usize, col: usize) -> &mut <F as Domain>::Elem {
        assert!(row < self.rows && col < self.cols, "Index out of bounds");
        &mut self.data[row * self.cols + col]
    }

    pub fn get_row(&self, row: usize) -> Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem> {
        assert!(row < self.rows, "Row index out of bounds");
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        for col in 0..self.cols {
            result.push(self.get(row, col).clone());
        }
        result
    }

    pub fn get_col(&self, col: usize) -> Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem> {
        assert!(col < self.cols, "Column index out of bounds");
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        for row in 0..self.rows {
            result.push(self.get(row, col).clone());
        }
        result
    }

    pub fn set_row(&mut self, row: usize, new_row: Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>) {
        assert!(row < self.rows, "Row index out of bounds");
        assert_eq!(new_row.len(), self.cols, "New row has wrong length");
        for col in 0..self.cols {
            *self.get_mut(row, col) = new_row[col].clone();
        }
    }

    pub fn set_col(&mut self, col: usize, new_col: Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>) {
        assert!(col < self.cols, "Column index out of bounds");
        assert_eq!(new_col.len(), self.rows, "New column has wrong length");
        for row in 0..self.rows {
            *self.get_mut(row, col) = new_col[row].clone();
        }
    }

    pub fn swap_rows(&mut self, row1: usize, row2: usize) {
        assert!(
            row1 < self.rows && row2 < self.rows,
            "Row index out of bounds"
        );
        if row1 != row2 {
            for col in 0..self.cols {
                let temp = self.get(row1, col).clone();
                *self.get_mut(row1, col) = self.get(row2, col).clone();
                *self.get_mut(row2, col) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn l_u_decomposition(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>, String>
    where
        F: Clone,
    {
        // Let base = field.base()
        let base = self.field.base().clone();
        // Let v_a = VectorAlgebra(base, cols)
        let v_a = VectorAlgebra::new(base.clone(), self.cols);
        // Let the_l_matrix = I (creates an identity matrix)
        let mut the_l_matrix: Vec<_> = self.field.int(1);
        // Let l_matrix = Matrix2D(base, the_l_matrix, rows, cols)
        let mut l_matrix = Matrix2D::new(base.clone(), &mut the_l_matrix, self.rows, self.cols);

        // For each pivot in min(rows, cols)
        for pivot in 0..std::cmp::min(self.rows, self.cols) {
            // Let pivot_row = self.get_row(pivot)
            let pivot_row = self.get_row(pivot);
            // If pivot element (pivot_row[pivot]) is zero, LU decomposition is not possible
            if base.is_zero(&pivot_row[pivot]) {
                return Err(
                    "LU decomposition without pivoting is not possible for this matrix".into(),
                );
            }
            // Let pivot_entry_inv = 1 / pivot_row[pivot]
            let pivot_entry_inv = base.inv(&pivot_row[pivot]);

            // For each row_idx in (pivot + 1) to rows
            for row_idx in (pivot + 1)..self.rows {
                // Let row = self.get_row(row_idx)
                let mut row = self.get_row(row_idx);
                // Let scale = row[pivot] * pivot_entry_inv
                let scale = base.mul(&row[pivot], &pivot_entry_inv);

                // row += -scale * pivot_row (Vector addition and scalar multiplication)
                v_a.add_assign(
                    &mut row,
                    &v_a.neg(&mul_vector(&v_a, scale.clone(), pivot_row.clone())),
                );

                // l_matrix[row_idx][pivot] = scale
                *l_matrix.get_mut(row_idx, pivot) = scale;
                // self.set_row(row_idx, row) (Sets the modified row back into the matrix)
                self.set_row(row_idx, row);
            }
        }
        // Returns the L matrix
        Ok(the_l_matrix)
    }

    pub fn p_l_u_decomposition(
        &self,
    ) -> Result<
        (
            Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>,
            Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>,
            Vec<<F as Domain>::Elem>,
        ),
        String,
    >
    where
        F: Clone,
    {
        let base = self.field.base().clone();
        let mut self2 = (*self.data).clone();
        let mut cloned_vector = Matrix2D::new(base.clone(), &mut self2, self.rows, self.cols);
        let mut pivot_row = 0;

        let mut the_p_matrix: Vec<_> = self.field.zero();
        let mut p_matrix = Matrix2D::new(base.clone(), &mut the_p_matrix, self.rows, self.cols);
        //let mut u_matrix = self.clone(); //Initializes the U matrix as a copy of the original matrix

        for pivot_col in 0..self.cols {
            // Find a non-zero entry in the pivot column
            let swap_row = (pivot_row..self.rows)
                .find(|&row| !base.equals(cloned_vector.get(row, pivot_col), &base.zero()));
            match swap_row {
                Some(swap_row) => {
                    // Swap rows in U and P matrices to bring the non-zero entry to the pivot position
                    cloned_vector.swap_rows(pivot_row, swap_row);
                    p_matrix.swap_rows(pivot_row, swap_row);
                    pivot_row += 1;
                }
                None => {
                    // If there are no non-zero entries in the pivot column, just proceed to the next column
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the diagonals of P to 1
        for i in 0..self.rows {
            *p_matrix.get_mut(i, i) = base.one();
        }

        // Run the LU decomposition on the permuted U matrix
        let l_u_result = cloned_vector.l_u_decomposition();

        match l_u_result {
            Ok(the_l_matrix) => Ok((the_p_matrix, the_l_matrix, cloned_vector.data.clone())),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }
}

use std::{error::Error, fmt};
impl<'a, T> fmt::Display for Matrix2D<'a, T>
where
    <T as Domain>::Elem: fmt::Display,
    T: Field,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        for row in 0..self.rows {
            for col in 0..self.cols {
                write!(f, "{} ", self.get(row, col))?;
            }
            writeln!(f)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn mul_vector<T>(
    f: &VectorAlgebra<T>,
    a: <T as Domain>::Elem,
    d: Vec<<T as Domain>::Elem>,
) -> <VectorAlgebra<T> as Domain>::Elem
where
    T: Field,
{
    f.mul(&d, &f.diagonal(a))
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*; // bring into scope everything from the parent module
    use abstalg::ReducedFractions;
    use abstalg::I32;

    fn test_p_l_u_decomposition(matrix: Vec<isize>, size: usize) {
        // This test assumes that the base field is rational numbers.
        let field = abstalg::ReducedFractions::new(abstalg::I32);
        let matrix_ring = MatrixRing::new(field.clone(), size);
        let mut matrix: Vec<_> = matrix.into_iter().map(|i| field.int(i)).collect();
        let mut matrix2d = Matrix2D::new(field.clone(), &mut matrix, size, size);

        // Decompose the matrix using the p_l_u_decomposition function
        let p_l_u_decomposition_result = matrix2d.p_l_u_decomposition().unwrap();
        let (mut p_matrix, mut l_matrix, mut u_matrix) = p_l_u_decomposition_result;

        // Convert the matrices back to Matrix2D form for printing
        let p_matrix2d = Matrix2D::new(field.clone(), &mut p_matrix, size, size);
        let l_matrix2d = Matrix2D::new(field.clone(), &mut l_matrix, size, size);
        let u_matrix2d = Matrix2D::new(field.clone(), &mut u_matrix, size, size);

        println!("P^-1={} L={} U={}", p_matrix2d, l_matrix2d, u_matrix2d,);

        // Multiply the resulting P, L, and U matrices
        let p_l = matrix_ring.mul(&p_matrix, &l_matrix);
        let mut p_l_u = matrix_ring.mul(&p_l, &u_matrix);

        //let p_l_u_2d = Matrix2D::new(field.clone(), &mut p_l_u, 4, 4);
        // Check that the product of P, L, and U is equal to the original matrix
        assert_eq!(matrix, p_l_u);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_p_l_u_decomposition_example() {
        test_p_l_u_decomposition(vec![
            11, 9, 24, 2,
            1, 5, 2, 6,
            3, 17, 18, 1,
            2, 5, 7, 1,
        ], 4);
        test_p_l_u_decomposition(vec![
            1, 3, 5,
            2, 4, 7,
            1, 1, 0,
        ], 3);
    }
 }
```

Aditionally, I've been thinking `abstalg` is not general enough for it doesn't support semirings, and seems implementing it might be a pain, which is a shame. But I like what I have so far.

Comment: Not a full review right now, but the first thing that jumps out at me is that you’re getting rows and columns by cloning them. You instead want to take views of them. If the matrix is implemented as a flat array, you could call `iter().advance(i).step_by(n)` to iterate over the elements of column `i` in each row. Operations on corresponding elements of two rows or columns could then be implemented with `row_iter.zip(column_iter).map(function_on_tuple)`.

Comment: If you want to copy the elements of a column into a packed array for efficient SIMD code, you probably want to do that in chunks equal to the native vector size of your target (32 bytes/256 bits on an x86 with AVX2).

Comment: the problem of mantaining references in rust then turns into ownership which is headache inducing, and sure I could use slices for rows but not for columns, and I didn't want to handle them differently, thats why they have the same input/output, but maybe I am missing a simpler way of doing this.